# What does '->' mean in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, operators, symbols

All,

Can you please tell me what this line means in Python?  I don't know if I'm using it properly.

def read_places_file(filename) -> List[PlaceInformation]:

We are defining a method that takes a parameter called, 'filename'.  And then what does the rest of the line mean?  What does the '->' operator mean?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: They are type hints, they allow IDE's and other tools to better analyze and infer types, and allow for things like autocompletion. See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Answer (score 1):

Those are [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) indicating the format of the function's output.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  So, after the function is run, the 'return' should be a list of 'PlaceInformation" objects?